# java: how to auto-generate a custom method for a variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter-setter

I've a situation where i want to define variety of behaviour for my fields.

```
class SomePage {
    //...

    @FindBy(id = "selectEthinicity")
    private WebElement ethinicitySelect;

    @FindBy(id = "someId")
    private WebElement usernameInputField;

     @FindBy(id = "buttonSubmit")
    private WebElement submitButton;


    public void selectEthnicity(String param) throws Exception {
        new Select(ethnicitySelect).selectByVisibleText(param);
    }

    public void selectEthnicityByIndex(String param) throws Exception {
        new Select(ethnicitySelect).selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(param));
    }

    public int getSelectEthinicityNumberOfOptions() {
        new Select(ethnicitySelect).getOptions().size();    
    }

    public void waitForOptionOfSelectEthnicityToLoad() {
       //logic to wait for an options of Ethinicity to load
    }

    public void selectEthnicity_Wait(String param) throws Exception {
        //wait 
        //select Ethinicity
    }

    public void selectEthnicityByIndex_Wait(String param) throws Exception {
       //wait and 
       //Select Ethnicity by einde
    }


    //custom method for input Field
    public String getUsernameInputFieldValue() {
        usernameInputField.getAttribute("value");
    }

    public void enterUsernameInputField(String param) {
        usernameInputField.sendKeys(param);
    }


    //custom method for button
    public void clickSubmitButton() throws PageValidationException {
        submitButton.click();
    }

    //...
}
```

Here I have a class SomePage which is a Page Object (Using Page Factory Pattern) which consist of fields (`WebElement`).

Based on the suffix of field names I need to create number of method. If suffix is `*Select` the field will have number of methods which can be Similar for all `select field`. If suffix is `*Button` it will have a method's that are needed for `button field`.

Can I generate the Custom Method based upon the `suffix of field names`.

> NOTE: IntelliJ Supports the modification of custom Getters and Setters but it doesn't allow multiple methods per field. It restricts to 1 Getter and 1 Setter per field. Which is not always the case as per example. I my have multiple setter ( kind of setter) or getter for a field.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/index.html)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create a class Radio/Button that has the defined functions? You could even do a superclass and extend it, and then all you'd use in the Temp class would be getters and setters for the individual button/radio and then call its getter/setter methods.

Comment: I've updated the example to which is close to what I'm using.. WebElement already has the function I need within it. but I'm using what's called PageObject Pattern so I need those methods in the page for each and every element(variable)

Answer (score 0):

**Generating Getters and Setters in IntelliJ IDEA :**

1. On the main menu, choose Code.
   Alternatively, right-click the editor and choose Generate on the context menu, or use Alt+Insert keyboard shortcut.
2. In the pop-up list that is displayed in the editor, select one of the following options:
   Getter
   Accessor method for getting the current value of the selected fields.
   Setter
   Mutator method for setting specified values to the selected fields.
   Getter and Setter
   Both methods for the selected fields.
3. In the Choose Fields to Generate Getters and Setters dialog box, select the desired fields.
   You can add a custom setter or getter by clicking browseButton and accessing Getter/Setter Templates dialog.
   If getters and setters for a field already exist, this field is not included in the list.
4. Click OK.
   For more info go to [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-getters-and-setters.html)

Comment: Getter and Setter only give the plain getter and setter.. I need to do some other stuffs on those variable.. 

Tried custom getter and setter.. I cannot add more than one getter / setter

Comment: @AmanTuladhar what do you mean with:  I cannot add more than one getter / setter

Comment: for example i have a variable x.. if I auto generate getter and setter i can have one getter for x and one setter or x.. but look at my example i have many methods for one variable.. not just getter and setter.. I need those to be auto generated too..

Comment: I followed the steps you gave me..(on link too) .. Where is a part to define may be two getter / setter

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate custom classes, but dynamic class generation is a fairly advanced feature, and from the sounds of your problem it's unnecessarily complex.

I think you should create a new class for these objects with the same functionality. You should read about Object-Oriented Programming because this is a fairly simple concept. Maybe your example is poor, but why are you redefining String functions for each button? Here's an example of a different design:

```
public class Button {
    private String text;

    public Button(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Then just declare a bunch of your new class.

```
class Temp {
    Button abcButton = new Button("abc");
    Button cdeButton = new Button("cde");

        // Instead of setAbcButtonToLower()
        abcButton.setText(abcButton.getText().toLowerCase());
        // Instead of getAbcButtonIndexOfChar()
        abcButton.getText().indexOf(c);
        // Instead of getAbcButtonSize()
        abcButton.getText().length();
}
```

Comment: The code that I've added there is just an example code... I'm not actually performing those actions on the String.... I just wanted to show you what I need in a simple way.. Could you please review my question again ignoring that my variable as a String ..  I just want a custom methods to describe the behaviour for those variable

Comment: I think my answer still applies. Create a class with all your common operations defined in it.

Comment: Using superclasses and subclasses would be my approach to this, not custom-tailored methods for every object. If every object uses the same exact methods, then those methods should be applied at the object-level.

Comment: @Compass If i use inheritance approach i will have to pass an element on which i want to perform an action. Your approach is very good.. that was what i was doing but thats not the solution I'm looking for...

Comment: @Samuel I've updated the example would you please review it once again and let me know if you understand what I'm trying to achieve..

Answer (score -4):

You cant generate custom methods automatically . For custom methods you have to define them that's why it is called custom .
best you can get are only basic getter and setter methods, I think you already got those
or
you can do it like this
class Button{
  string button
}

class buttonProperties{

int buttonLength;
int buttonSize;

public int getbuttonSize(){

```
return buttonSize;
```

}
. 
.
.

}

Comment: That's extremely wrong. Lombok instruments the code accordingly.